# Cannot run NUnit Tests on Build Agent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, nunit, teamcity-7.1

I am having trouble understanding how to make the NUnit Tests run from TeamCity. The basic setup for the tests is that they are .cs files; e.g. I have a class called Rule.cs, I have a RuleTest.cs for the tests for the rules. What I don't understand is how to run the tests...

[image: Image of TeamCity Build Configuration]

Currently, I am pointing to the .dll in the correct folder (I manually checked, and the .dll is there). Are the tests supposed to be in a separate library (.dll) or am I pointing to the wrong file?

Comment: Try to specify full path to the file (without *'s). Also, it is not clear what is the problem, is there any exception when you run it?

Comment: Okay... how would I go about checking the full path of the agent?
Is there a way for me to point to the working directory of the project?
And, I found something else I was doing wrong, so I will be putting the tests into a separate class library as well as pointing directly to the library.

Comment: You can use %teamcity.build.checkoutDir% property, which will be replaced at runtime.